# Regex Pattern to find Markdown link definitions

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I'm trying to find all link definitions in a markdown document:

```
See you saturday!
  [1]: //xxxx.com/assets/uploads/2014/01/0334633e32aa851cac33d55f4b30a1c4.jpg
  [2]: http://a_url.com/aaaa-2013
  [3]: //xxxx.com/assets/uploads/2014/01/cfdd0c7ce2bbef9b0536455c0914c2f8.jpg
```

I'm using this pattern (taken from Michelf's markdown parser http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown)::

```
/
^[ ]{0,3}(?:\[(.+?)\][ ]?:) # id = $1
[ ]*
\n?             # maybe *one* newline
[ ]*
(?:
<(.+?)>         # url = $2
|
(\S+?)          # url = $3
)
[ ]*
\n?             # maybe one newline
[ ]*
(?:
(?<=\s)         # lookbehind for whitespace
["(]
(.*?)           # title = $4
[")]
[ ]*
)?  # title is optional
(?:\n+|\Z)
/xm
```

Well this works fine until you use urls with relative schema's, in the above input example, `preg_match_all` only returns the last link, but with this input:

```
See you saturday!
  [1]: //xxxx.com/assets/uploads/2014/01/0334633e32aa851cac33d55f4b30a1c4.jpg
  [2]: http://a_url.com/aaaa-2013
  [3]: http://xxxx.com/assets/uploads/2014/01/cfdd0c7ce2bbef9b0536455c0914c2f8.jpg
```

It returns all three and I can't see why.
I suspect it has something to with the greedy behaviour of regex's.

Comment: Not sure how you're getting different results. [Seems to work fine](http://regex101.com/r/hU8gD7)?

Comment: well, that just throws more incognita into my problem :/

Comment: Not sure what it was, seems something like caché because started working now... +1 for pointing me to a better online regex tester that the one I was using.

Comment: All is well that ends well then :D